# Trying to call an init function with Cocos2D-x C++

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to reproduce this turorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vb6QfatNQI&list=PLRtjMdoYXLf5H1O_AOZtc415UmSQCVs93&index=3&ab_channel=SonarSystems

**But my init function is never called, I checked with breakpoints.**

This is a part of my code on SplashScene.cpp :

```
Scene* SplashScene::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = Scene::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);

    return scene;
}


// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool SplashScene::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if (!Layer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }

    SonarCocosHelper::UI::AddCentredBackground(MAIN_MENU_BACKGROUND_FILEPATH, this);
    scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(SplashScene::SwitchToMainMenu), 5);

    return true;
}
```

This is a part of my code on AppDelegate.cpp (like in the tutorial):

```
// create a scene. it's an autorelease object
auto scene = SplashScene::createScene();

// run
director->runWithScene(scene);

return true;
```

Comment: Which part of the code is supposed to call `init`?

Comment: Where do you actually create a `SplashScene` object? All I see are two `Scene` objects. Presumably you meant to write `layer = SplashScene::create();`?

Comment: #UnholySheep
I don't know, in the tutorial, I don't see if the function is called manually :/
I tried "scene->init();", but it does nothing

#Botje
Yeah I didn't see it ! thank you ! :)

Comment: I voted to close as a typo because this question is ultimately not useful to future readers except those who happen to make the same typo on the same YouTube tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

#Botje give me the answer :

In my implementation of Scene* SplashScene::createScene(), I replaced

```
auto layer = Scene::create();
```

by

```
auto layer = SplashScene::create();
```